# Expected value to have no heads

Tags: expected-value

This question was asked in an interview of a Quantitative finance company.
You have $\textit{n}$ fair coins with either heads or tails facing up arranged in a row.
You play a game in rounds described as follows:

In each round check the number of coins having heads. Let it be $\textit{k}$. Now flip the $\textit{k}^{th}$, i.e., if it is head change it to tail, or if it is tail change it to head.
Continue this game until all the coins facing up are tails.
Find the expected number of flips to get the desired arrangement of coins.

I was using the approach that if I have k heads at any instant:
$E_{k}$ describes the expected number of steps to reach k heads. We need to find the value of $E_0$.
\begin{equation}
E_k=\frac{k}{n}E_{k-1}+\frac{n-k}{n}E_{k+1}
\end{equation}
I don't know whether this approach is right. Please suggest some better methods.

Comment: Is there anything random in this game aside from the initial arrangement of coins?

Comment: Hi! I think it's better if you try figuring out the dynamics of the situation. Suppose $n = 10$ and initially coins $1$, $3$, $8$, and $10$ are heads. Figure out the progression toward the all-tails state. After you figure that out, see if you can generalize how this progression happens.

Comment: @user6247850 no there is no other random than the initial arrangement

Comment: @BrianTung I am unable to arrive at a general result. It would be great if you could help me out.

Comment: What is the sequence of $k$ in the example scenario I described?

Comment: Your approach is likely wrong, because the number of flips is dependent on the arrangement, and not just the number of heads that are up. (Also, note that you forgot to +1 for the current flip)

Comment: @CalvinLin could you please suggest what should be the approach? I am unable to arrive at the answer

Comment: I suggest to condition on "largest index $k$ that is a heads".

Comment: Do you have any information on how the coins are initially distributed, i.e. are they distributed uniformly?

Comment: @CalvinLin  They are distributed in any possible way initially like they can have any possible number of heads initially in any possible manner. Like there are $2^n$ initial states possible.

Comment: @H.sapiensrex please look at the above comment

Comment: @MdKaifFaiyaz At which firm was this asked ?